# Proguard isn't working with Chartboost?

Tags: android, proguard, chartboost

I'm getting proguard error when trying to compile project with Chartboost Android SDK:

```
 [proguard] Unexpected error while editing code:
 [proguard]   Class       = [com/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/d]
 [proguard]   Method      = [b(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/chartboost/sdk/Libraries/CBOrientation;]
 [proguard]   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Invalid instruction offset [65674] in code with length [236])
```

I added those lines to `proguard.cfg` but this didn't help:

```
-libraryjars ./libs/chartboost.jar
-keep class com.chartboost.sdk.**  { *; }
```

I tried to compile project both on Mac & PC, but result is the same. Does anyone can help me with this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error has gone after update to beta version of their SDK.